# how to disable scrolling button or Icon When we are at the end of scrolling screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview

I have two button/Icon with left (Back Button) and Right(Forward) button.. Now I have 7 screens in scrollview. with horzontal scrollview. now I want that when user at first screen the left button should be disabled and when user at end last screen the right button should be disabled. please help
here is my screen

```
<View>screen 1</View>
<View>screen 2</View>
<View>screen 3</View>
<View>screen 4</View>
<View>screen 5</View>
<View>screen 6</View>
```

and below these screens here is my coding logic

```
 <View style={{ paddingRight: "25%" }}>
            <IconNB
              name="arrow-left"
              size={90}
              color="#000080"
              onPress={() => {
                currIndex.current -= 1;
                this.scroll.scrollTo({ x: screenWidth * currIndex.current });
              }}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={{ paddingLeft: "25%" }}>
            <IconNB
              name="arrow-right"
              size={90}
              color="#000080"
              onPress={() => {
                currIndex.current += 1;
                this.scroll.scrollTo({ x: screenWidth * currIndex.current });
              }}
            />
          </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *currIndex.current* for that.

```js
{currIndex.current !== 0 && 
<IconNB
              name="arrow-left"
              size={90}
              color="#000080"
              onPress={() => {
                currIndex.current -= 1;
                this.scroll.scrollTo({ x: screenWidth * currIndex.current });
              }}
            />
}
```

This will make the left button visible if *currentIndex.current* is not *0*.

Comment: but when I save ==0 then its no visible in all screen i only want to notvisible in only first screen and last screen

Comment: currIndex.current , is this a variable or something saved in state ?